# Android, setting column sizes in TableLayout

Tags: android, tablelayout

So, I'm creating TableLayout from code by inflating layout files. I'm trying to get first row spanning over two columns, and each next row contains two TextViews: key and value. Problem is that value can be quite long, so I was playing around with settings `android:stretchColumns`, `android:shrinkColumns` in TableLayout xml. Now Key column and Value Column looks fine, but first, spanned, header is wider that screen size.

Current situation of my files looks like this:

tale_row.xml:

```
 <TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingTop="5dp"
     android:paddingBottom="5dp"
     android:paddingLeft="10dp"
     android:paddingRight="10dp" >
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/key"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />"
 </TableRow>
```

header_row.xml:

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_span="2"
        style="@style/group_separator_style"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

</TableRow>
```

table.xml:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1" >
</TableLayout>
```

Any ideas, what could be the reason? Setting attributes `clipChildren` and `clipToPadding` to true didn't help.

Comment: use layout_width="match_parent" in the header cell

Comment: unfortunatelly, it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like setting `android:stretchColumns="1"` and `android:shrinkColumns="1"` solved the problem